# Sum Types vs. Type Classes vs. Records

Tags: haskell, typeclass, algebraic-data-types

Which of the following three approaches would be the most idiomatic to implement some kind of rarity for items in an RPG?

The sum type approach "feels" like it's the right one since rarities seem like a "closed set" (or immutable? idk if that's the right word).
But if this were defined in a library then I would not be able to add any more rarities which seems odd.

```
data Rarity = Rarity { symbol :: String, value :: Int }

common    = Rarity "C" 1
rare      = Rarity "R" 2
legendary = Rarity "L" 3
```

```
data Rarity = Common | Rare | Legendary

symbol :: Rarity -> String
symbol Common    = "C"
symbol Rare      = "R"
symbol Legendary = "L"

value :: Rarity -> Int
value Common    = 1
value Rare      = 2
value Legendary = 3
```

```
class Rarity r where
  symbol :: r -> String
  value :: r -> Int

data Common = Common
instance Rarity Common where
  symbol _ = "C"
  value _ = 1

data Rare = Rare
instance Rarity Rare where
  symbol _ = "R"
  value _ = 2

data Legendary = Legendary
instance Rarity Legendary where
  symbol _ = "L"
  value _ = 3
```

Comment: The second one (Sum type) feels right to me, but if this is a library intended for others to use and be able to add their own, then as you say this won't work. In that case the third one (typeclass) seems better than the first to me, but I may be missing some subtleties.

Comment: The type class solution is worse than the first one, IMO. In a function `foo :: Rarity r => r -> ....` you can't do anything to the argument `r` except for asking symbol and value. Hence, it could have been a record as in the first solution. If you know no more rarities will ever be needed, then I would instead use the second solution.

Comment: Actually on reflection I agree with @chi that the record is better than the typeclass approach - I'd been concerned about possibly being able to use the record to construct "illegal" rarities, but then in the typeclass approach you still allow any combination of String and Int, the only difference being that it takes a bit more boilerplate, which isn't a good thing.

Comment: In the typeclass approach, instead of having a "value" method, I would simply make the class a subclass of `Ord`. That way the actual mechanism of comparison would be handled by the instance itself. One could even have "composite" rarities whose `Ord` instances would be defined in terms of the `Ord` instances of its components. This is compatible with both the record and sum type solutions.

Comment: None of the above. I would want a central registry of rarities, so that I could check consistency things like "all rarities have different values". So I would want an API that looked something like the existence of two new abstract types, `Registry` and `Key`, together with operations like `registerRarity :: String -> Rational -> Registry -> Maybe (Key, Registry)` and `lookupRarity :: Key -> Registry -> Maybe (String, Rational)` or something like that. `Rational` instead of `Int` ensures that you can choose a value for your new rarity that's between any two existing rarity values.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The type class approach you have shown is not very ergonomic in practice.

Presumably you want to have items with a rarity attribute. But what type should the rarity field be? `Common`, `Rare`, and `Legendary` are all *separate* types, so you can't just have `data Item = Item { ..., rarity :: Rarity }` (Not to mention the supposed additional rarity levels added by the client program, if this is in a library).

You can have `data Item r = Item { ..., rarity :: r }`, but now the type of a list (or any other generic collection) of items has to specify what *single* rarity level all the items in it have (e.g. `[Item Common]`). That isn't how you want to use rarities in practice (since e.g. a player's inventory can contain items of different rarities!).

You can work around that by using an existential type:

```
{-# LANGUAGE GADTs #-}

data Item
  where Item :: Rarity r =>
          { ...
          , rarity :: r
          }
          -> Item
```

But now this is basically isomorphic to your first proposal (with `data Rarity = Rarity { symbol :: String, value :: Int }`), only way more complicated to use. Since you can't do anything with a value of an unknown type that is constrained to be in the `Rarity` type class other than call `Rarity` methods, and all those do is get you a `String` and an `Int`, you might has well have just used a record of a `String` and an `Int` to begin with, and saved all the extensions and boilerplate.

So now we're down to the first two versions: record or sum type.

A potential advantage of the record version is that you (or any client code) can come up with arbitrary new rarity levels. A big potential **disadvantage** is that you (or any client code) can come up with arbitrary new rarity levels, without any guarantee of consistency with rarity levels used in other items.

Whether that's a feature or a problem really depends on how you intend to process the `String` and `Int` that make up a rarity level. If you can truly write engine code in your RPG library that handles those completely agnosticaly of any properties between them, then the record is the right way to go. But my instinct is for RPG rarity levels, you won't do that. You'll rely on an ordering, you'll rely on a given `String` rarity code corresponding to *the same* `Int` value each time you see it, etc etc.

I would go for the static sum type when writing a individual RPG. It just fits my conception of rarity levels better (as you say, within one game it normally **should** be a closed set, not arbitrarily extensible).

For writing an RPG library, I would use a type class, but differently than you used it.

```
class Rarity r where
  symbol :: r -> String
  value :: r -> Int

data GameOneRarity = Common | Rare | Legendary

instance Rarity GameOneRarity
  where symbol Common = "C"
        symbol Rare = "R"
        symbol Legendary = "L"

        value Common = 1
        value Rare = 2
        value Legendary = 3


data GameTwoRarity = Boring | Cool | Awesome

instance Rarity GameTwoRarity
  where symbol Boring = "B"
        symbol Cool = "C"
        symbol Awesome = "A"

        value Boring = 100
        value Cool = 1000
        value Awesome = 10000000
```

I don't have a separate type for each new rarity **level**, I have a separate type for each rarity **scheme**. The idea would be for each game to define its own rarity type. An individual set of rarities is not extensible, but the library code can handle arbitrary schemes with whatever rarity levels the game designer wants (so long as they can implement `symbol` and `value` for them).

The inventory system I write generically in the RPG library can use types like `[Item r]` to ensure that all of the items it considers together use *the same* rarity system (avoiding the possibility of having to answer non-sensible questions like whether a Legendary item from one game is more or less valuable than a Cool item from a different game) but each item can have its own rarity level within that system.

Comment: I probably cannot thank you enough for this answer! Simply wonderful. One question: in the library scenario, you suggest the library only including the Rarity type class, right? In that case, there is no way to make sure that the clients of the library use a sum type (rarity scheme) like you've done, so they may end up with the original design, hence with the heterogeneous list problem. Am I correct?

Comment: @GrumpyRodriguez Yes the idea is for the library to only define the `Rarity` type class, not any rarity type. But the library also comes with an API implementing a customizable RPG engine! So there will be an API with other types for things like inventories, loot tables from monsters, equipment slots for characters, as well as functions for doing things with all of those. Nearly all of them will end up with a type variable for the rarity type: e.g. `Inventory r`, `equip :: Item r -> Character r -> Character r`. (1/2)

Comment: @GrumpyRodriguez At each use of the API the client will have to instantiate the variable to some *single* type. If they have something like `Common`, `Rare`, `Legendary` as separate types they'll have extreme difficulty using the library API at all (e.g. `equip someLegendaryItem` requires a `Character Legendary` as its next argument; a character who can only equip legendaries!). So it just really won't work for them to attempt to use more than one type for their rarity scheme. The library doesn't **technically** force them to use a single sum type for a rarity scheme, but in practice... (2/2)

Comment: @GrumpyRodriguez This is the same problem as the heterogenous list problem, just appearing with other types than lists. It'll show up all over the place, which is why the separate types aren't a great idea for how an RPG API is likely to work. It forces you to keep things parameterised over the rarity level separate, or to be able to convert between them, which isn't what we want here (note that it **could** be what we want in a different context; in fact it's exactly what I'm guessing is wanted wrt the rarity schemes from each game, which is why I say they should be different types). (3/2)

Comment: great explanation, thanks. Especially for pointing out that the same pattern emerges across other types. Can you please confirm that when you say " It forces you to keep things parameterised over the rarity level separate" you mean "anything that uses separate types end up being a separate type", i.e. the requirement to define type specific behaviour creeps up. That's a great insight if I got it right, but did I get it right ? :) Once again, many thanks!

Comment: @GrumpyRodriguez Basically yes, you got it right. If you have `data TypeA = ConsA { fieldA :: A }` and `data TypeB = ConsB { fieldB :: B}`, then obviously you can't mix `TypeA` and `TypeB` because they're different types. If you parameterise the type on the field type so you have `data PType t = PType { field :: t }`, now you can use just the one type. But `PType A` and `PType B` are **still** different types! So they still can't be mixed in a list. What you've gained is you can write code that works for any single `PType t`, but not for both at once (without more advanced extensions).